# Resistor in my amp design caught fire, is my design incorrect?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, vacuum-tube

I'm working on the final stage of my guitar amp. This stage needs to take the line-level signal (~1vpp-~2vpp) from the FX_RCV jack and swing it hard enough to drive the EL34 output tube. This stage of the amplifier is solid state to save on $.

I'm using an LND150 (500v depletion mode MOSFET) to boost the voltage and an IRF820 (500v enhancement mode MOSFET) to supply enough current to drive the output tube (when it goes into saturation).

When I fired the FX loop recovery section up, I had one resistor nearly explode (R29), and another smolder (R28) (Always wear safety glasses around high voltages!).

My wiring appears to be correct :( Is something wrong with my design around the LND150?

## EDIT

I figured it out! My wiring is so *not* correct! The gate on the LND150 is the middle pin, and the gate on the IRF820 is the left pin. This means ALL of my MOSFETs are wired incorrectly. I made the assumption that did not vary from the transistors I've used in the past vs these MOSFETs and the lesson is to RTFM!

- http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/supertex_lnd150-522923.pdf
- http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/427/91059-106635.pdf

[image: claideamh-v1.4.1.png]

[image: 20160924_134701.jpg]

Comment: What are the voltage and power ratings of your resistors?

Comment: * R28=Metal Film 100k 1/2w
* R29=Metal Film 470R 1/4w
both 500v

Comment: Wild speculation: you put in a 100Ω resistor as R28 by accident. When the FET turned on, this dumped all of the energy in C22 (and maybe C21) through R28-Q3-R29. Q3 immediately died, failing shorted. The remaining energy gets divided over R28 (100Ω) and R29 (470Ω). Most of the energy is dissipated in the larger R29, which explodes.

Comment: Help us out here with some DC voltage measurements, Q3 grid and anode voltages, and Q4 grid and cathode for a start.

Comment: We do need some measurements including the state of the components. I'm for instance looking at what happens if Q4 shorts out, as well as Q3. R29 looks like it got a lot of current through it, and with 366 volts to play with, well...

Comment: eek, I can't turn the amp back on without fireworks, I'll remove the resistors and measure Q4. The PSU is regulated/solid state, so it _does_ kick out the exact voltages on the schematic and was operating properly at the time of the fire (I keep a voltmeter attached)

Comment: You can check the conductance of the Mosfets with the power off, with a multimeter :) I think this is why people dealing with valves often power the circuit via a Variac, heh.

Comment: The pinouts on MOSFETs is different that I'm used to! Wiring incorrect, I'm lucky it's even worked at all so far haha.

Comment: Well, at least they didn't all blow up, heh. I dearly wish that they'd standardise all transistors so that the middle one is the base/gate/etc and the current flows from left to right :D

Comment: You should excise your "edit" and put it as an answer (perfectly acceptable to answer your own question on SE) - in general, things burning is a sign that something is wrong, whether you call this one "design error" or "wiring error" is somewhat moot.

Comment: One last question/comment, the Drain/Source on my IRF820s were also reversed. Do you think they're destroyed? They never heated up and oddly enough were amplifying signal still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you calculated the power dissipation for R28 and R29?

The schematic is a bit fuzzy, but I take R28 to be 100K and R29 to be 470K.  Those are large values, but you have the supply voltage given as 366V, which makes the total power rather high despite the high resistance.

I find 0.2 Watt for R29, and less than 0.1 Watt for R28.  These are worst case (Q3 completely conducting,) but I think you need resistors rated for higher power.  Like, 1 Watt.

---

Now that the values have been corrected, things change drastically.

R28 will dissipate 1.3Watt worst case.
R29 will dissipate 0.06W worst case.

If R28 fails to a lower resistance, then the power through R29 goes up, which would destroy it as well.

Comment: Those resistors in the picture are already pretty fat, they look like 1/2W to me. Even if they're not, 0.5W through a 1/4W resistor will not cause instant fire and/or explosions. So I suspect something else was wrong.

Comment: @marcelm:  Judging by appearance, those are metal film resistors.  The smaller one would be 1/8 Watt and the large one 1/4 Watt.

Comment: The maximum dissipation I can find through that part of the circuit is 3.7mA (due to the 100k resistor) which works out as 1.72W for R28 and .01W for R29. That's if the Mosfet is fully on. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: First, thank you everyone for taking a moment to answer and add your thoughts. The 100k resistor R28 was 1/2w rated, the .5k R29 was only 1/4w, which initially I thought was enough, and yes the were metal film

Comment: Here's a circuit sim: http://bit.ly/2dpSpao It looks like R28 is dissipating 1.3w with the MOSFET at full conduction, yikes. This doesn't really explain what happened though, why would the MOSFET be at full conduction? I had a sine wave hooked up to the input, but it the FX_SND volume was all the way down

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher if R28 were to fail short (or nearly) that would pump a lot of current through the FET and R29. (edit) Is the FET failed short? Then you've just got 366V across the two resistors...

Comment: Hmmm.  Something strange here.  366V across 570K is only .23 Watts.  How do you get 1.3W?

Comment: R29 is 470Ω, not 470kΩ

Comment: That's a major difference.

Comment: @IanBland I'll check that when I get back home. Still confused why the MOSFET would go full conduction with practically no input signal... perhaps because the LND150 is depletion mode?

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher -- yeah, a depletion FET will be ON at 0V Vgs